# Excel Formula too many arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to see what's wrong with this formula but I'm not seeing it:

```
=IF(F5:M5;"*Accepted*";IF(F5:M5;">"&TODAY();IF(F5:M5;"*N/A*";"Verified";"Pending")))
```

Do i missed something? What I'm trying to do is, if the values of F5 to M5 are one of theese conditions, then the column "State" will be verified, if one of the values are not Accepted, greater than today(), or "N/A", then State will be "Pending".

| Document1 | Document2 | Document3 | Document4 | Document5 | Document6 | Document7 | Document8 | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Expired | Expired | 31/12/2020 | 30/12/2020 | Accepted | Accepted | N/A | 24/11/2021 |  |
| 24/12/2020 | 44197 | 30/12/2020 | 30/12/2020 | Accepted | Empty | N/A | 44563 |  |
| Expired | Expired | Rejected | 44234 | Accepted | Accepted | N/A | N/A |  |
| Expired | Expired | Incomplete | Incomplete | Accepted | Empty | N/A | N/A |  |
| 44378 | 44228 | Expired | 44203 | Accepted | Accepted | N/A | Rejected | Pending |
| Accepted | Accepted | Accepted | 44197 | Accepted | Accepted | N/A | N/A | Accepted |

Comment: `F5:M5;"*Accepted*"` will not do what you think.  `IF` uses the actual expression like `F5:M5>TODAY()`

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @ScottCraner Maybe I should use `F5:M5 = "*Accepted*"`?

Comment: Correct ^ you need to input a boolean response to the first argument of `IF`. So the order/column of where you find these values doesn't matter? I would think you would only expect to see certain values in certain columns. If so, you can simplify here

Comment: It's weird cause if I `=IF(F5:M5="*Accepted*";IF(F5:M5;">"&TODAY();IF(F5:M5="*N/A*";"Verified";"Pending")))` I get this `#VALUE!`

Comment: @Martinez - share sample data so we can test on our end...

Comment: But that will not work, also it hard to help because the formula itself does not make sense.  How can a cell be a string and a date.  I assume one of the cells is like `"*Accepted*"` and one of the cells has a date and one is like `"*N/A*"` you will need to use AND() and specify the actual cell to test in each

Comment: You're evaluating an array, be sure to enter it as an array formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: I put a sample on the question, cells can be a string or a date, depending. We can make it the other way, if one of those documents are Rejected, Incomplete etc and less than today, then Pending, else Verified.

Comment: Update the state column so we know what your expected output is

Comment: Done, to be Verified, all documents must be "Accepted", greater than today(), or "N/A", if one of them is another thing like "Rejected", or less than today(), then Status will be Pending.

Comment: So the `N/A` doesn't really matter here so you should remove that.

Comment: Well depending on how you want to focus the formula, if which things have to be right, or which things have to be wrong.

Comment: The thing is what is wrong with this formula `=IF(F5:M5="*Accepted*";IF(F5:M5;">"&TODAY();IF(F5:M5="*N/A*";"Verified";"Pending")))`

Comment: Are you always looking in columns `F:M`?

Comment: Yes, always that range in different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 criteria you need to check

1. Values equal `Accepted`
2. Values equal `N/A`
3. Dates are larger than `Today()`

---

If you individually sum the criteria for each row you should end up with `8` (*i.e. all eight cells in your columns meet one of the criteria listed above*). If the count is less than 8 **then** one of the values does not meet the criteria and should be `Pending` as a result.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:H2,"Accepted")+COUNTIF(A2:H2,"N/A")+COUNTIF(A2:H2,">"&TODAY())=8,"Verified","Pending")
```

Comment: BAH!!! stupid phone call made me late.  A little shorter version: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A2:H2,{"Accepted","N/A"}))+COUNTIFS(A2:H2,">"&TODAY())=COLUMNS(A2:H2),"Accepted","Pending")`

Comment: Fan of the array check rather individually counting Accepted and N/A

Comment: Good solution to not being able to add the TODAY() formula to the array @ScottCraner, I didn't think of that

Comment: @ScottCraner something is wrong with your formula mate

Comment: @Martinez you need to change the `,` to `;` as is your local setting.  and make sure all the references are referring to the correct cells.

Comment: We all used `A:H` to test solutions and we all used `,` instead of `;` so you will need to make those changes to all solutions @Martinez

Comment: Nice! Awesome guys thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want, you can add an IF to get "Verified" and "Pending" instead of True and False, but it works:

`=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:H2;$L$1:$N$1;-1)))`

Where `L1:N1` is an array containing my 3 lookup values: Accepted, Today and N/A, and it's entered as an Array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
Tested on this dataset:

[image: Dataset testing formula compared to expected result]

Comment: Simple solution. vry nice. It doesn't rely on the `>8` like mine has which seems like a big improvement

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to add an array in the formula instead of a range reference but the Today() made it complicated